# How do I preserve state when hot reloading in a standard SvelteKit dev environment?

Tags: state, vite, svelte, sveltekit, hot-reload

I have a pretty standard out of the box Svelte dev environment setup based on [these docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/creating-a-project) in early 2024.

My vite.config.js file currently looks like this:

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()]
});
```

My svelte.config.js file currently looks like this:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter()
    },
    preprocess: [vitePreprocess()]
};

export default config;
```

I see that the `svelte-hmr` plugin [supports preserving state](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-hmr/blob/6d8bb85e02090ba47cf2881f53c7a827c238293b/packages/svelte-hmr/README.md) but it's disabled by default. I also know that this plugin is somewhere in my build tooling because it's in package-lock.json as a dependency of `vite-plugin-svelte`.

I'm totally new to SvelteKit and Vite. I just can't figure out where to set that config flag.

I *can* add `// @hmr:keep-all` into the  tag in my one and only component right now and it works. I'd prefer to set it globally.

I acknowledge that preserving state has caveats. I'm too used to React dev environments with that kind of setup, and I can't work with SvelteKit without it.

Comment: State is restored automatically. If you lose data, then something is going out of sync. E.g. inputs are not bound.

Comment: It's not just inputs. It's everything. I create state values using `let` and they all go away on any edit, unless I add `// @hmr:keep-all`. Then it works perfectly.

Comment: Apparently that *used to* work by default but has been turned off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs on HMR explain [why this was turned off and how to reenable it](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-hmr/tree/master/packages/svelte-hmr#preservation-of-local-state):

> If you want this behaviour for all the state of all your components, you can enable it by setting the `preserveLocalState` option to `true`.

```js
// svelte.config.js
export default {
    vitePlugin: {
        hot: {
            preserveLocalState: true,
        },
    },
};
```